# Using the Datadog logs and RUM SDKs sends multiple requests when errors are being thrown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, datadog, rum

I have the following issue:

**Trigger**

An uncaught exception is being thrown and datadog logs SDK sends request to log the incident.

**Expected outcome**

One request is sent/incident and the incident is logged only once in Datadog UI.

**Actual outcome**

Datadog logs SDK sends many requests/incident (between 1k-2.5k) and the incident is logged many times in Datadog UI.

**Additional Information**

When disabling the Datadog RUM SDK, then the Datadog logs SDK behaves as expected. However, I want to run them both, so this is not an option at the moment.

I am using version `3.1.3` for both `@datadog/browser-logs` and `@datadog/browser-rum` packages.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate the issue:

[Many requests being sent for one uncaught exception example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xX8L.png)

This is the code I am using to initialise both logs and RUM SDKs:

```
    import { datadogLogs } from '@datadog/browser-logs';
    import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.DATADOG_CLIENT_TOKEN) {
            const environment = getEnvironment();
            const config = {
                site: 'datadoghq.eu',
                clientToken: process.env.DATADOG_CLIENT_TOKEN,
                service: typeof DATADOG_SERVICE !== 'undefined' ? DATADOG_SERVICE : undefined,
                env: environment ? `${environment}` : undefined,
                proxyHost: process.env.PROXY_HOST
            };
        
            datadogLogs.init(config);
        
            
                if (process.env.DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID) {
                    datadogRum.init({
                        ...config,
                        trackInteractions: true,
                        applicationId: process.env.DATADOG_APPLICATION_ID
                    });
        
                    datadogRum.setUser({
                        name: service.getName(),
                        email: service.getEmail()
                    });
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, Upgrading both Datadog Rum and logging to 3.6.13 fixed this for me:

```
"@datadog/browser-logs": "^3.6.13",
"@datadog/browser-rum": "^3.6.13",
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else:

1. Use `localhost`, not custom domain names. For some reason, DD_RUM.getInternalContext() didn't work for custom domain names.
2. Install versions of both RUM and logs - latest and possibly the same version. Incase you want specific varying versions, check the dependency packages for the datadog packages on the package.lock. It can be different which can throw errors.